# Use Serializable or modified Singleton?

Tags: java, android, serialization, singleton, serializable

I have an `Application` with a `List` of `Objects` on the main screen.
When clicking on one of them, I'm transferring the user to the next `Fragment`.
Then I have more 3 `Fragments` which are setting(manipulating) the object fields.
My question is, is it right instead of implementing the `Serializable` `interface` and pass the `Object` using Bunde I'll do kind of Singleton. 
Something like this (I know that for Singleton I must do the empty constructor private).

```
public class Father {


    private static Father instance;
    private String name;
    private int age;



    Father() {
    }


    public static Father getInstance(Father father) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Father();
            if(father != null) {
                instance = father;
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }



       Father regularFather = new Father();
        regularFather.setAge(35);
        regularFather.setName("Danny");

        Father regularFather2 = new Father();
        regularFather2.setAge(44);
        regularFather2.setName("Mike");

        Father regularFather3 = new Father();
        regularFather3.setAge(15);
        regularFather3.setName("Tom");

       Father.getInstance(regularFather2).setName("Mike32");


 System.out.println("regularFather name is: " + regularFather.getName()
                + " \n regularFather2 name is: " + regularFather2.getName()
                + " \n regularFather3 name is: " + regularFather3.getName()
                + " \n Instance name is: " +  Father.getInstance(null).getName()

        );
```

I test it, it works great, but my question is, is it right to do so and what if it can cause problems in the futere?

Comment: Not clear, where are you using `Serializable`?

Comment: Hi @Alexandre Dupriez. I'm not using yet. That actually my question, use the approach that you see above or use Serializable and pass the object in Bundle.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your use case, but at a high-level, if `Father` is a data object, singleton does not seem the right pattern. If you serialise your object, you will end up with a copy of the `Father` instance. One question is which instance of `Father` do you need to update?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons#comment78107_137975) can help.